# Arithmetic progression of squarefree integers?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, square-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Let $x$ be a given positive integer.

I'm intrested in the longest arithmetic progression of squarefree integers within the interval $(x,x^2)$.

Both constructive and nonconstructive results.

For clarity with longest I meant the most elements.
For example 1,3,5,7 is longer than 10,20,30.

I have no lack of Ideas relating to this but none are formal or even convincing.

For instance - inspired by sieve theory - I considered:

Longest progression $~$

$$x^2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{9}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{25}\right)\dots$$

(Product over odd primes up to $x$)

Or $\frac {\pi(x)}{\zeta(2)}$

Etc etc

But those are handwaving arguments.

Maybe its just a Deeper understanding of the Chinese remainder, Fermat little and quadratic reciprocity I need?

Comment: Consider $3, 7, 11, 15 , 19, 23$ or $11,
 47,
 83,
 119,
 155,
 191,
 227,
 263,
 299,
 335,
 371,
 407,
 443,
 479,
 515,
 551,
 587,
 623,
 659,
 695,
 731,
 767,
 803,
 839$

Knocking off the first  term of each of these gives a progression of the kind you are looking for. Not sure whether these are maximal, but trust they are helpful examples.

Comment: You might take a look at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0684v2.pdf ("Squarefree Numbers in Arithmetic Progressions," by Ramon Nunes).

Comment: @BarryCipra That paper doesn't appear to be about squarefree numbers in arithmetic progression, but about the distribution of squarefree numbers in arithmetic progressions.  This is analogous to Bombieri-Vinogradov for primes, but the OP is asking more about the analogue of Green-Tao.

Comment: It might be simpler to consider the inverse problem: given $k$, how large $x$ must be for $(x,x^2)$ to contain a $k$-AP of squarefree numbers?  Considerations similar to prime APs apply here: the common difference must be divisible by $p$ for every $p \le \sqrt{k}$, so you can restrict to a fixed congruence class modulo some small primorial.  But the nice thing about the squarefree case is that once you quotient out enough primes, then the relative density can be taken arbitrarily close to $1$, which gives immediate lower bounds on the length of arithmetic progressions (even tuples).